# The random () function returns an integer from 1 to 10

Tags: php

how to Ensure that it can not return one of the values ​​in the array $ excluded.

This is my code

```
$exclus=array(1,4);
function ramdom(){
   $resultat=rand(1,10);
   return $resultat;
}

echo "Random Num : ".random()."\n";
```

Comment: it is not a `random()` call as `ramdom()` as you defined in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function randWithout($from, $to, array $exceptions) {
    sort($exceptions); // lets us use break; in the foreach reliably
    $number = rand($from, $to - count($exceptions)); // or mt_rand()
    foreach ($exceptions as $exception) {
        if ($number >= $exception) {
            $number++; // make up for the gap
        } else /*if ($number < $exception)*/ {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}
```

and call it:

```
$exclus=array(1,4);
$random_number = randWithout(0,10,$exclus);
```

Comment: it does not work properly. if you have exeption 2,3,4   from 1 to 5

Comment: i cant post ..  can you help me with a last one ..  really appreciate thank

Comment: How should I change the code to look for a number like 22 is found, and that the elements are strings as 20 and 12 should  not be found?

here is my code

$list = array("c12", 33, 6, "020b", 22, 31);

function cherche($dans, $quoi) {
                foreach($dans as $item) {
                               if ($item === $quoi) {
                                 return "trouvé $quoi";
                               }
                }
                return "pas trouvé $quoi";
}

echo cherche($list, 12);
echo "\n";
echo cherche($list, 22);
echo "\n";
echo cherche($list, 20);

Comment: well, for this I suggest you to create another question to describe well the problem and I'll try to resolve it @user3172273

Comment: don't forget to accept the right answer to help other guys with your same problem please :) @user3172273

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$exclus = array(1,4);
function ramdom()   {
    $resultat = rand(1,10);
    while(in_array($resultat, $exclus)) {
        $resultat = rand(1,10);
    }
    return $resultat;
}
```

?>

Should work, but I didn't test it...

Comment: How it works: It picks a random number and checks whether it is one of the forbidden ones. If yes, then it picks a new one; if not, it returns it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an online demo of the code below: https://eval.in/87096

```
function ramdom() {
   $resultat = rand(1,10);    
   $exclus = array(1,4);
   if(in_array($resultat,$exclus)) {
      return ramdom();
   }
   else {
     return $resultat;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3172273: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_search` :

```
$exclus=array(1,4);
function random(){
   $resultat=rand(1,10);
 return array_search($resultat,$exclus) ? ramdom() : $resultat
}
```